# Community Cleanup Duty: Game Recommendations

Tags: support, questions, game-recommendation

There are still [QUITE some questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgame-recommendation%5D+closed%3A0+locked%3Ano) out there that are game recommendation questions and not closed or locked.

It might take months to go and close and lock them all by hand, especially since game recommendations were deemed unfit for the stack [**5 years ago**](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic-revisited) and still people dig them up regularly, at which point we have to take affirmative action of closing - and many old folks downvote those necromancer answers.

Can we have the mods go through and either close or lock that backlog?

**UPDATE** The last items entered the closure queue as of a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### We are equipped to handle this through community moderation.

We have pretty low volume review queues here. SSD wrote in [this answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6232/please-do-not-flood-queues-with-old-posts-found-by-searching-without-first-clear/6233#6233):

> Reviewers can just take bites out of it, and bow out when decision fatigue rears its head. Pressing <kbd>Skip</kbd> when at all unsure helps a lot in that regard, too. Others will pick it up and take care of a few more, until the whole queue has been reviewed. Crowdsourcing at work!
>
> It's much preferable for the queue to balloon occasionally, and be handled by the normal crowdsourcing mechanisms it has for precisely such events, than for people to *refrain* from flagging when they see something that deserves a flag. All that refraining results in is different people having to—redundantly—each stop and ponder how much flagging is “too much,” wasting user energy that would be better spent just about anywhere else on-site or off, just so that we can, inexplicably, prevent the flood-management measures designed into the system already from needing to be used.

We should be just fine to handle it without moderator assistance, and as I am writing this, things seem to be moving through the queue smoothly:

[Image of the review queue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4pwS.png)

#### It's best to do it in small to medium sized batches.

Because:

[image]

If you send in more questions than we have active reviewers with votes remaining, that's a problem. In hindsight, I should have saved some close votes just in case I needed to close something more pressing before my votes reset.

Comment: After I sent ome 19 or such into the queue. :3

Comment: @Trish Yeah, you did that, and now the community is handling it appropriately. No need for moderator action.

Comment: Just there are enough questions that need closure to spend days with clothing *nothing* but those.

Comment: @Trish If that's the case, I recommend *not* flooding the close queue with these questions, as that may prevent new questions that *haven't* been dormant for several years from being actioned in a timely manner. Remember, users only have a limited number of close votes per day, and if they get used up closing a flood of old questions that you keep sending to the queue, there may not be any available to close new questions that have problems.

Comment: I only got 6 in my queue, so the batch could have been bigger before becoming a problem for the active reviewers. 20 seems a small enough contingent, we could probably handle around 40 without issues.

Comment: @Akixkisu looks like we closed 30 yesterday.

Comment: @Akixkisu I personally went through 19 yesterday. Today I only saw about 6 or 7, so I assume that Trish is taking my advice and only flagging/close voting a few per day.

Comment: @RevanantBacon today I got 4.

Comment: I don't think we need to slow down the close votes at all. We can handle even an increase in queue volume beyond this flagging spree at a daily workload. Issues might arise when we have 60ish close votes/day.

Comment: I went with some 5 or such a day, but as only a handful actually does moderate, our 24/day/person are quickly depleted if a spree comes in.